# Python LSTM generates all the same output value

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I tried to set up a LSTM model with input matrix 7 columns, ca. 1650 rows
Output matrix is 1 column, 1650 rows.

My model code is shown in the following.
Problem, the prediction does in every 1650 columns have the same value 26,19...

Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Edit: I updated the code.
In svt.csv are 8 columns with ca. 8000 rows...Y is seperated from that, so that Y has one column and X has 7 columns.

Edit2: I realized that predict has shape (1657, 20, 1) why not (1657,1) ???

```py
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

from matplotlib import pyplot
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks

df_svt = pd.read_csv("svt.csv", sep=";")


df_svt = df_svt.iloc[6980:]

df_svt = df_svt.iloc[:8158]

df_y = pd.DataFrame(df_svt.y)


df_y_train = df_y.iloc[:6501]

df_y_test = df_y.iloc[6501:8158]

y_train = df_y_train.to_numpy()

y_test = df_y_test.to_numpy()


df_svt = df_svt.drop(columns=["y"])

df_svt = df_svt.drop(columns=["Date"])

df_x_train = df_svt.iloc[:6501]

df_x_test = df_svt.iloc[6501:8158]

x_train = df_x_train.to_numpy()

x_test = df_x_test.to_numpy()


train_X = x_train.reshape(6501,1,7)

test_X = x_test.reshape(1657,1,7)

train_Y = y_train.reshape(6501,1,1)

test_Y = y_test.reshape(1657,1,1)

trainX = []
trainY = []
testX = []
testY = []

ts = 20
timestep = ts

def create_dataset(datasetX,datasetY, timestep=10):
    dataX, dataY = [],[]
    for i in range(len(datasetX)-timestep-1):
        a = datasetX[i:(i+timestep),0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(datasetY[i+timestep,0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

timestep=ts
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train_X, train_Y, timestep)
timestep=ts
testX, testY = create_dataset(test_X,test_Y,timestep)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=70,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2]) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=70, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=70))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=5, batch_size=32,verbose=1
model.summary()
predict = model.predict(testX)
print(predict)
```

Comment: Could you provide code which reproduces the issue? In your code the training data is missing and there are other errors

Comment: I updated it, so you can see the full code now. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try with just 1 `LSTM` at first, with more epochs, and see the results. What about the `loss`, does it go down during training? Without the `csv` file, it cannot be reproduced

Comment: I can not upload it here as it seems?! Yes loss goes down but keeps constant after some epochs.

Answer (score -1):

You are using *return_sequences=True* in your LSTM layers which means that all outputs from each timestep are fed to the next timestep. This is most likely what you want to do in a sequential model, but you need to remove it from the last *LSTM layer*, where you want the outputs from the last timestep.

```
model.add(LSTM(units=70,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2]) ))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=70, return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=70))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Comment: In the last LSTM layer is no return_sequences = True... so what do you mean? Thank you!